# Relationship between line and surface integrals of scalar fields and measure on manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, integration, manifolds, differential-forms

I am wondering how to derive the well-known formulas for line and surface integrals of scalar fields, starting from measures on submanifolds.

I've managed to derive the formulas  for curve length and surface area and integrals of vector fields, but what about general integrals of any scalar field? Where can I find information about this derivation?

Comment: Could you provide information about what "well-known formulas" you refer to and perhaps how you did it for curve length and surface area? The latter would make it more clear what you want.

Comment: @md2perpe We defined the measure on a submanifold $M$ as one that satisfies $L^M(A \cap V) = \int_{\Phi^{-1}(A)} J_d(\Phi) dL^d$, where $A$ is a measurable subset of $M$, $\Phi : U \rightarrow V$ is the parametrization and $J_d$ is "d-th jacobian".

I aim to get from this to e.g. $\int_C f dl = \int_a^b f(\phi(t)) | \phi'(t)| dt$, if $\phi$ is C curve's parametrization.

Comment: Curve length: $L^M(V) = \int_{\Phi^{-1}(V)} J(\Phi) dL^1$, if the curve is given by $\Phi: (a, b) \rightarrow V$. This turns out to simby be $\int_a^b | \Phi'(t) |dt$